# Hide main form but not from Task Bar

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar, delphi-5

I have searched here and found some offerings but none work for me as D5 (win8) does not appear to have the...

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar:=True;
```

It tosses an "undeclared identifier" error.

I have tried...

```
WindowState:=wsMinimized;
```

...but that shows as a small title-bar at the bottom of the screen. Interestingly enough, when I use the "-" at the top right of the main form, it does exactly what I need. It hides the main form but leaves the icon on the Taskbar that restores the main form when clicked.

How can I get the form to hide but still leave an icon on the Taskbar?

Comment: `wsMinimized` should do what you want. Can you show a picture of this small title-bar that's left behind?

Comment: Also, while I have to give you credit for using such an old (but good, the splash screen is still my favourite) version of Delphi on Windows 8, I'd also like to encourage you to upgrade to a Win8-supporting version.  You'll get so much! New modern and awesome language features, new IDE features, inbuilt support for modern Windows features, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
Application.Minimize;
```

Comment: Aaarrggh, I knew there had to be a way. Thanks